# Network gets disabled when "PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK" is used to turn screen off, only on Samsung phones

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am working on a SIP-based audio/video calls app in android and facing a weird issue **only** on Samsung phones.

The problem is that during in-app calls (with power-saver mode enabled) as soon as proximity sensor is triggered to turn screen off, device's mic/speaker cuts off and when phone is moved away from face (screen turns on) then instantly the mic/speaker returns back to life.

After a bit of troubleshooting, it seems when screen turns off, phone is cutting all network access of the app causing the speaker and mic blackout.

This is the implementation I am using to turn screen off during calls:

```
screenLock = ((PowerManager) context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG");
        screenLock.acquire();
```

and using this to turn screen back on:

```
if (screenLock != null && screenLock.isHeld())
        screenLock.release();
```

Any thoughts on how to go about fixing this? This is only happening on Samsung phones when their battery-saver mode is enabled.

**tl;dr** During in-app call, network gets disabled when proximity sensor triggered and back to normal when proximity wake-lock is released

Comment: there is a feature in samsung phone called 'smart network' which disable network when screen is off. Try disabling the feature from settings to check if thats the problem

Comment: Smart network doesn't really do anything. However, putting the app in un-monitored apps list in battery settings fixes it.

Now that's something that user has to do manually, any other solution?